# generalize function operating on STL set to all collections

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I created this template function to find and delete and item from collection of shared_ptr

```
template<class T>
bool FindAndDelete(set<shared_ptr<T>>& collection, shared_ptr<T> item)
{
    auto foundItem = find(collection.begin(), collection.end(), item);
    if(foundItem != collection.end())
    {
        collection.erase(foundItem);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Question:
How could I generalize it more to cover all collections? (vector, list, etc...)

for example

```
template<class K, class T>
bool FindAndDelete(K<shared_ptr<T>>& collection, shared_ptr<T> item);
```

Note: I come from C#, so maybe the code is a bit off :) Correct me please

Comment: If you are new to c++ this may use too many templates for your liking, but on [this video(from the start until around 14 mins)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-3-of-n) on Channel9 Stephan T. Lavavej gives an interesting approach to creating some functions `erase` (to remove a specific value) and `erase_if` (to remove any value that satisfies a predicate) that work for vector, deque, list, forward_list, set, multiset, map, multimap and the unordered variants.

Comment: @llonesmiz thanks, actually I watched his videos about smart pointers and collections, very explanatory! I like templates, but sometimes it confuses me because I was used to much simpler generic types in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove elements from a container, then something like this would work:

```
template<class K>
bool FindAndDelete(K& collection, typename K::value_type item);
```

Bear in mind that the `value_type` of maps is an `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>`, so you may want to provide special versions for those, for example

```
template<typename T, typename K>
bool FindAndDelete(std::map<T,K>K& collection, 
                   typename std::map::<T,K>::key_type key);
```

and similarly for `std::multimap` and C++11 `std::unordered_*` variants. These containers have `find` member functions that are more efficient than `std::find`, so it would be worthwhile to have dedicated implementations of `findAndDelete` to take advantage of this.

You could also have a look at [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and the [erase remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) as an alternative to your implementation for non-associative containers. This could be more efficient in the case where you have duplicates.

Comment: how would you restrict using this on collections only? I mean, in C# you could do that with `class Clazz<T> where T : ICollection` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: @mizi_sk you wouldn't, because collections have no common base class or interface. The compiler would tell you if you are doing something wrong. Or you could use `SFINAE` to check whether T has some attribute that all containers have.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <template<typename> class K, typename T>
bool FindAndDelete(K<shared_ptr<T> > &collection, shared_ptr<T> item);
```